# Can you modify an internal NodeJS module temporarily?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

I want to put some middleware into the FS module temporarily to log all read/write activity from Node, so that I can do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fsLogger = require('fs-logger');
const someModule = require('some-module');

fsLogger.bind(fs);
someModule.doMagic();
fsLogger.unbind(fs);
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

The modern approach to doing this with JavaScript is through a Proxy Object. Here is the description of them from the docs:

> The Proxy object is used to define custom behavior for fundamental
> operations (e.g. property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function
> invocation, etc).

Here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy